# Neo4J Cypher combine 2 queries into one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I got 2 node types, let's say A and B, and a relationship with a property, let's call it 'a_has_b' with the property 'value'

First I want to count the number of relationships a specific node of type A has.

```
MATCH (a:A)-[r:a_has_b]->(b:B) 
WHERE a.id='123'
RETURN COUNT(r) as count
```

I also want to get the top n B's ordered by the property from the relationship

```
MATCH (a:A)-[r:a_has_b]->(b:B)
WHERE a.id='123'
RETURN r, b
ORDER BY r.value
LIMIT 3
```

Now, it's clearly I am doing the same thing twice, changing the return value.

How can I combine them together to get both needed results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `collect` and `range`:

```
MATCH  (a:A)-[r:a_has_b]->(b:B) 
       WHERE a.id='123'
WITH   a, 
       r, 
       b 
       ORDER BY r.value
RETURN a, 
       COUNT(r) AS count, 
       COLLECT([r,b])[0..3] AS rels
```